Blockcypher "Error reading signatures and pubkeys: Invalid signature, wrong length"
I was creating a program in python to create, sign, and send ltc transactions with blockcypher's api, but I get an error message
Error reading signature and pubkey: Invalid signature, wrong length: 09aedc8947493cb7d0005fc85bf1363128e1fb413e38c101aa3f66d7f911de304c8aa65243873cfa6 efe2131c87c1.
Code(Keys are withheld)
import requests
import time
import binascii
import hashlib
from ecdsa import SigningKey, SECP256k1

BASE_URL_LTC = "https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/ltc/main"
BLOCKCYPHER_API_KEY = ""
FROM_ADDRESS = "Lg1Pb7CntUo3NcPE6KxjSsmPejfrxUoihS"
TO_ADDRESS = "ltc1qdrnfkezjddndueycqmq09qnxuywy2j8adz6cjw"
AMOUNT = None
PRIVATE_KEY = ""
PUBLIC_KEY = ""

def ltcToLitoshi(ltc:float):
    litoshi = int(ltc * 100000000)
    return litoshi

def signTransaction(tx, privateKey, publicKey):
    privateKeyBytes = binascii.unhexlify(privateKey)
    privatekeyObject = SigningKey.from_string(privateKeyBytes, curve=SECP256k1)
    toSign = tx["tosign"]
    signatures = []
    pubkeys = []
    for data in toSign:
        dataBytes = binascii.unhexlify(data)
        signatureObject = privatekeyObject.sign_deterministic(dataBytes, hashfunc=hashlib.sha256)
        signature = binascii.hexlify(signatureObject).decode()
        signatures.append(signature)
        pubkeys.append(publicKey)
    tx["signatures"] = signatures
    tx["pubkeys"] = pubkeys
    return tx

def sendTransaction(tx:dict):
    url = f"{BASE_URL_LTC}/txs/send"
    payload = {
        "tx": tx["tx"],
        "tosign": tx["tosign"],
        "signatures": tx["signatures"],
        "pubkeys": tx["pubkeys"]
    }
    res = requests.post(url, json=payload, params={"token": BLOCKCYPHER_API_KEY})
    if res.status_code == 201:
        return res.json()["tx"]["hash"]
    else:
        print(f"Error: {res.status_code}")
        print(res.json())
        return None

def createAndSendTransaction(fromAddress:str, toAddress:str, amount:float, privateKey:str, publicKey:str):
    transactionData = {
        "inputs": [{"addresses": [fromAddress]}],
        "outputs": [{"addresses": [toAddress], "value": ltcToLitoshi(amount)}]
    }
    res = requests.post(f"{BASE_URL_LTC}/txs/new", json=transactionData, params={"token": BLOCKCYPHER_API_KEY})
    if res.status_code == 201:
        tx = res.json()
        while True:
            if not sendTransaction(signTransaction(tx, privateKey, publicKey)):
                time.sleep(35)
            break
        return True
    else:
        return False

createAndSendTransaction(FROM_ADDRESS, TO_ADDRESS, AMOUNT, PRIVATE_KEY, PUBLIC_KEY)

Response from blockcypher
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "error": "Error reading signatures and pubkeys: Invalid signature, wrong length: 09aedc8947493cb7d0005fc85bf1363128e1fb413e38c101aa3f66d7f911de30b37559adbc78c3059101dece3783e599f15f248ac082ccdd5c3ef91ab911d670."
    }
  ],
  "tx": {
    "block_height": -1,
    "block_index": -1,
    "hash": "fec526f7b6e18d955a706feb47cdadfe978c08d289547e1f9ebdea8d756a6db8",
    "addresses": [
      "LM38Sqm7bwwq3mjseEojhdtsv3HehT7eAU",
      "ltc1qdrnfkezjddndueycqmq09qnxuywy2j8adz6cjw"
    ],
    "total": 29800,
    "fees": 8000,
    "size": 553,
    "vsize": 553,
    "preference": "low",
    "relayed_by": "2405:6580:8e40:c00:354d:e1db:fedc:21fa",
    "received": "2024-09-13T23:46:30.202800438Z",
    "ver": 1,
    "double_spend": false,
    "vin_sz": 3,
    "vout_sz": 2,
    "confirmations": 0,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "prev_hash": "cc1cb19057580747360d2b640318f1daf2fd8193b547d12fabd022dfa7ab3a4e",
        "output_index": 0,
        "output_value": 15000,
        "sequence": 4294967295,
        "addresses": [
          "LM38Sqm7bwwq3mjseEojhdtsv3HehT7eAU"
        ],
        "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash",
        "age": 2754804
      },
      {
        "prev_hash": "8f4deafb14c0a944455e8d7800d95505464aa06fc41b10528d8badd071fcacd2",
        "output_index": 0,
        "output_value": 11400,
        "sequence": 4294967295,
        "addresses": [
          "LM38Sqm7bwwq3mjseEojhdtsv3HehT7eAU"
        ],
        "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash",
        "age": 2754854
      },
      {
        "prev_hash": "ce17bcf70c33cf0af7b078363d41c046a2897c3201626887be215d0f2bde226c",
        "output_index": 0,
        "output_value": 11400,
        "sequence": 4294967295,
        "addresses": [
          "LM38Sqm7bwwq3mjseEojhdtsv3HehT7eAU"
        ],
        "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash",
        "age": 2754869
      }
    ],
    "outputs": [
      {
        "value": 22800,
        "script": "001468e69b64526b66de649806c0f28266e11c4548fd",
        "addresses": [
          "ltc1qdrnfkezjddndueycqmq09qnxuywy2j8adz6cjw"
        ],
        "script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash"
      },
      {
        "value": 7000,
        "script": "76a91413e42d31864add8e1bd522cdb18aa0d1add8f23388ac",
        "addresses": [
          "LM38Sqm7bwwq3mjseEojhdtsv3HehT7eAU"
        ],
        "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash"
      }
    ]
  },
  "tosign": [
    "",
    "",
    ""
  ]
}

Although not included in this code, I thought it would successfully sign the transaction since it uses the public key in the response from blockcypher's api and the private key when creating the wallet, but it did not.
